# MISRA C-2012 Rule 10.3 violation due to adding of two 8 bit variables which resulted in 32 bit

Tags: c, misra

I am getting  MISRA C-2012 Rule 10.3 violation: Implicit conversion of "var4 + var5" from essential type signed 32-bit int to different or narrower essential type unsigned 8-bit int" for the below code.

```
int8_t var4 = -10;
uint8_t var5 = 15;
uint8_t var6 = var4 + var5;
```

How "var4 + var5" is interpreted aa 32 bit int since each one are 8-bit size.

And also what is the correct way of fixing this ?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359404/why-did-my-tool-throw-a-misra-error-here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to **integer promotions**.  This is detailed in section 6.3.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> *2* The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>     the rank of `in`t and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the
>   integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.

Because an `int8_t` and `uint8_t` have lower rank than `int`, variables of these types are promoted to `int` when used in an expression.  In the case of:

```
uint8_t var6 = var4 + var5;
```

Both `var4` and `var5` are promoted to `int`, and the result of the `+` operator is also of type `int`.  That value is then assigned back to `var6`, which is a `uint8_t`, which can result in truncation of the value.

The best way to handle this would be to first verify that the result cannot overflow, then explicitly cast the result:

```
uint8_t var6 = (uint8_t)(var4 + var5);
```

Comment: *first verify that the result cannot overflow*: more precisely: if the result could overflow type `int`, it would be undefined behavior because the operation is a signed integer addition, but given the range of the operands, this cannot happen. Conversely, if the result is outside the range of `uint8_t`, casting it to `(uint8_t)` is perfectly defined, and is indeed implicit, but might not have the intended effect, which the MISRA rule violation is warning you about.

Comment: `(uint8_t)(var4 + var5);` violates MISRA-C:2012 rule 10.4: "both operands of an operator in which the usual arithmetic conversions are performed shall have the same essential type category".

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is [implicit type promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). There is 3 implicit promotions in that single line, which is dangerous and sloppy style. You have both integer promotion/usual arithmetic conversions and an implicit lvalue conversion in a single line of code.

You must understand how these coversions work in C, in order to write bug free C code, but you must also understand them in order to use MISRA-C. In fact, one of the purposes of MISRA-C has always been to educate programmers about implicit type promotions - you'll also find explanations in the MISRA-C document.

Your code actually violates several MISRA-C:2012 rules. Not only 10.3 which is concerned about the implicit lvalue conversions, but also 10.4:

> Both operands of an operator in which the usual arithmetic conversions are performed shall have the same essential type category.

`var4` is essentially signed and `var5` is essentially unsigned. Therefore it is not enough to just cast the result to the appropriate type. To get MISRA-C compliant code you must cast both operands to the same type. Or better, use variables of appropriate type to begin with: it does not make much sense to store the result of `-10 + 15` in an unsigned variable. Either you need signed numbers or you don't.

To get MISRA-C compliant code which is also fully portable, this should be a type that cannot get implicitly promoted, like `uint32_t`.

```
uint8_t var6 = (uint8_t) ((uint32_t)var4 + (uint32_t)var5);
```

alternatively

```
int8_t var6 = (int8_t) ((int32_t)var4 + (int32_t)var5);
```

This expression is rugged, professional C as it does not contain a single implicit promotion. It is self-documenting code, as it shows that the programmer knows about and has considered implicit type promotions. It does *not* affect performance compared to the expression with only 8 bit operands, since the compiler is free to optimize.